# Converting NSMutableString to NSUrl in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, nsxmlparser, nsurl, nsmutablestring

I actually stuck with a problem while parsing xml-file from a dynamic url in Objective-C.
The Parser works fine for the whole project, but now I have to set a dynamic URL to parse the needed XML-File.

I have two Variables: One for the BaseURL and one for the Params.
Here is my documented Code:

```
    //The Baseurl
NSMutableString* baselink = [NSMutableString stringWithString:zimmertyp.typlink];   

//Adds the params to URL
[baselink appendString:aSlice.link];

//In Log it shows the right url to my XML-File with params
NSLog(@"Selected-URL: %@", url);

//I tried to convert the String to NSURL here
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: baselink];


NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
self.navigationItem.prompt = @" ";

//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

Everytime the Parser tries to walk through, I get:

```
2011-02-16 16:40:03.371 Project[15566:207] Selected-URL: http://xml.projectwebsite.de/price/doppelzimmer.xml
    ?Zimmertyp=Doppelzimmer+Classic
2011-02-16 16:40:03.373 Project[15566:207] Error Error Error!!!
2011-02-16 16:40:03.374 Project[15566:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'
```

It seems like the NSUrl is empty, or am I wrong?
The App crashes right at the point when the Parser initialized with the url.

Can anyone tell me what's my fault?

greeting,
Zarakas

Comment: Print the URL in code or debugger and find out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. The AppendString method added whitespaces to the String... dunno why. I escaped the spaces from the string. Now parser works fine.. ;)